# How to get public key from a certificate in iPhone program?

Tags: iphone, encryption, rsa

Now I have a certificate which includes a public key, I want to get the public key from it in iPhone SDK programming, and encrypt a string by RSA with the public key. What should I do?

Answer (score -1):

```
SecKeyRef publicKeyReference = NULL;
NSMutableDictionary* queryPublicKey;

SecItemCopyMatching((CFDictionaryRef)queryPublicKey, (CFTypeRef *)&publicKeyReference);
```

publicKeyReference - is your public key representation;
queryPublicKey - is your certificate representation;
SecItemCopyMatching - function that allows you to retrieve public key from certificate!